# What is the effect that the size of the correlation window (in pixels) has on the matching performance of stereo algorithms?

Tags: stereo-vision

While stereo algorithms perform matching, they usually compare pixels within a region around the feature. I would like to know what effect the size of that search window has on the matching performance.

And what sort of features don't get detected if you go on increasing the size?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "matching performance?" Accuracy? Speed?

Comment: I am more concerned about if increasing region prevents some (correct) matches that were earlier being made to now not be made because of the scale of those features or other edge cases.